# Excel currency (FX) daily rate

Tags: excel, vba, currency, rate

What's the easiest free way to get an approximate daily FX rate in the current version of Excel (Office 365 / Feb 2019).

I'm not interested in historical data, I just want the last known day rate from currency X to currency Y, and have that auto refresh only once on opening the document.

There used to be some VBA that could extract the data from some finance sites, but I can't find any that still work.

One possible solution is openexchangerates.org but how would I use their API in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro from Matteo NNZ is really nice :)

As well as it is possible by using Data -> From web (insert the link of website with table and select the table). After then the excel will automatically gathers information from website. In order to refresh the informations You need to select cell in new table and click the Query tab -> Refresh.

For refreshing everytime when you open Your workbook just look on the right side of Your sheet and You will see Your table under Queries and Connections list. Hit rigt mouse button on proper table -> properties and select "Refresh data when opening the file". You can add the timer to refresh data e.g. every one minute :)

In my case I use link : https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=USD&amount=1

Click ok save workbook and it is done.

Examples:

1) properties for refreshing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRTsM.png

2) information about table https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Odrh.png - here You have currency from around the world :)

Answer (score 0):

The following function currently works on one of my workbooks:

```
Public Function getConversionRate(ByVal ccy1 As String, ByVal ccy2 As String) As Double
    Dim htm As Object
    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "https://themoneyconverter.com/" & ccy1 & "/" & ccy2 & ".aspx", False
        .send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With
    With htm.getelementbyid("cc-ratebox")
        myRate = Right(.innerText, Len(.innerText) - 10)
        getConversionRate = myRate
    End With

    htm.Close
End Function
```

Sample usage:

[image]

Just to make it clear, the function above uses a simple `XmlHttp` request on a specific website (in my case it's https://themoneyconverter.com, sample usage being `https://themoneyconverter.com/EUR/USD`), then searches the conversion price accordingly in the HTML obtained in the response by the request (for this specific site, the value is contained into an element with id `cc-ratebox`).

You can of course do the same thing with any other website, all you'll need to do is to adapt the request (i.e. the part `.Open "GET", "your adapted link"`) and the retrieval of your value (i.e. the part `With htm.getelementbyid("cc-ratebox")` - as far as this website provides a simple access to their values through `XmlHttpRequest`

Comment: Thank you Matteo NNZ, much appreciated. I wish I could mark 2 answers. I have a similar macro (there are a few versions floating around) but it stopped working, which is why I asked the question. It's possibly not the macro, but rather the URL I used, so your answer does provide a solution.  I'm marking @Adorovosky 's answer only because I've not seen this before, and it relates to some relatively new Excel features.